# pushwoosh onMessageReceive xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, pushwoosh

**ok, hello i am trying to implement pushwoosh notification on my xamarin.android application**

i am on a stage were notification sent to client and when i click the notification it should redirect me on a certain activity and ui, here is my code

```
private void DoOnMessageReceive(String message)
{
var messageJson = new JSONObject(message);
if (messageJson.GetString("title") == "akotube")
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Second));
    //intent.PutExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent, messageJson.ToString());
    intent.PutExtra("message", "akotube");
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

`
but i cant make it work , this is my reference [pushwoosh](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-sdk-samples/blob/master/Xamarin/Android/PushwooshSample/MainActivity.cs)

---

**EDIT**
Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.pushwosh.sample" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <!--library-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <!--
    Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.
    NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
    where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <permission android:name="com.pushwosh.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.pushwosh.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <!-- The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
    to target higher versions. -->
    <application android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:label="PushWosh">
        <meta-data android:name="PW_APPID" android:value="CXXXX-XXXX"/>
        <meta-data android:name="PW_PROJECT_ID" android:value="AXXXXXXXXX"/>
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.pushwosh.sample"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

here is my class

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        var goSecond = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGo);
        goSecond.Click += goSecond_Click;
        var unregister = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Unregister);
        unregister.Click += unregister_Click;

        _mMessageReceiver = new LocalMessageBroadcastReceiver {Activity = this};

        _mRegisterReceiver = new LocalRegisterBroadcastReceiver {Activity = this};

        _manager = PushManager.GetInstance(this);


        //Register for push!
        //_manager.RegisterForPushNotifications();

        CheckMessage(Intent);

    }

 private void RegisterReceivers()
    {
        var intentFilter = new IntentFilter(PackageName + ".action.PUSH_MESSAGE_RECEIVE");

        if (MBroadcastPush)
        {
            RegisterReceiver(_mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

        RegisterReceiver(_mRegisterReceiver, new IntentFilter(PackageName + "." + PushManager.RegisterBroadCastAction));
    }

    private void UnregisterReceivers()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(_mMessageReceiver);
        UnregisterReceiver(_mRegisterReceiver);
    }

    class LocalMessageBroadcastReceiver : BasePushMessageReceiver
    {
        public MainActivity Activity { private get; set; }

        protected override void OnMessageReceive(Intent intent)
        {
            Activity.DoOnMessageReceive(intent.GetStringExtra(JsonDataKey));

        }
    }

    class LocalRegisterBroadcastReceiver : RegisterBroadcastReceiver
    {
        public MainActivity Activity { private get; set; }

        protected override void OnRegisterActionReceive(Context p0, Intent intent)
        {
            Activity.CheckMessage(intent);
        }
    }

private void CheckMessage(Intent intent)
    {
        if (null != intent)
        {
            if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent))
            {
                DoOnMessageReceive(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent));
            }
            else if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.RegisterEvent))
            {
                DoOnRegistered(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.RegisterEvent));
            }
            else if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.UnregisterEvent))
            {
                DoOnUnregisteredError(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.UnregisterEvent));
            }
            else if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.RegisterErrorEvent))
            {
                DoOnRegisteredError(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.RegisterErrorEvent));
            }
            else if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.UnregisterErrorEvent))
            {
                DoOnUnregistered(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.UnregisterErrorEvent));
            }

            ResetIntentValues();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to determine the cause of this from your implementation of DoOnMessageReceive alone considering the number of steps involved in getting this to work according to this doc even assuming you have your permissions on the android manifest correct and your application tag.  https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/xamarin-android/ Could you post those and the classes you are using to implement this.

Comment: Do you have at the beginning of your class [IntentFilter (new string[]{"PACKAGE_NAME.MESSAGE"}, Categories = new string[]{"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"})] where com.pushwosh.sample is your package name?

Comment: yes i have `[IntentFilter(new[] { "Com.PushWosh.Sample" }, Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]`

Comment: Why do you have this commented?
//Register for push!
//_manager.RegisterForPushNotifications();

Comment: Do you have the "OnNewIntent" override implemented and calling CheckMessage? in your MainActivity?

Comment: because i have a button to register my device ` void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _manager.OnStartup(this);
            _manager.RegisterForPushNotifications();
            RegisterReceivers();
            //UnregisterReceivers();
        }` yes i have `protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            CheckMessage(intent);
        }`

Comment: they are all working fine, but on `OnMessageReceive` class it wont execute this code `var messageJson = new JSONObject(message);
            if (messageJson.GetString("title") == "akotube")
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Second));
                //intent.PutExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent, messageJson.ToString());
                intent.PutExtra("message", "akotube");
                StartActivity(intent);
            }`

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code in the class so I dont have to keep asking you what you have and don't have.

Comment: also I'd recommend you add some logging to all the doOnRegistered, doOnRegisteredError, doOnUnregisteredError... etc and related to see what is actually getting hit. If you don't already have it implemented.

Comment: here is all the code [link](http://pastebin.com/NsUquVWL)

Comment: i add some log and here is error when i tap the notification `Can't launch activity. Are you sure you have an activity with 'com.pushwosh.sample.MESSAGE' action in your manifest?`

Comment: Not a lot of anything obvious calling out to me, I'd say try to go exactly off the example and register on OnNewIntent instead of on button click and moddify your OnPause/OnResume to unregiser/register recievers and uncomment the register for push notification if you are not getting any responses from your alerts. Also I'd also say you should be using the debugger instead of the alerts so aren't doing any weird blocking while you are alerting anything. I could be wrong on this but I do think they are blocking so you could be breaking something accidentally without knowing it.

Comment: Also is this the correct intent for your Main?      com.pushwoosh.test.xamarin.app.MESSAGE

Comment: sorry but where do i find this `com.pushwoosh.test.xamarin.app.MESSAGE`?

Comment: Its not anywhere, but you have it as your IntentFilter on your MainActivity

Comment: Also Change your namespace back to PushWosh so it matches up everything else in your manifest.

Comment: Either that or change your Category to com.pushwoosh.test.xamarin.app.Message in the Manifest for your application

Comment: Apologies if this comes off a bit over generalized. Its been a bit  since I've done some solid Xamarin\Android stuff.

Comment: is it possible that, when i tap the notification then go to a specific activity, if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Category in Activity needs to match your Activity's Intent filter

Also

Getting the intent and starting the activity on your DoOnMessageRecieved

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
intent.PutExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent, messageJson.ToString());
StartActivity(intent);
```

Where the `SecondActivity` is the activity you want to navigate to.

Comment: it work on the sample app of pushwoosh but not on mine.

Comment: why is that when the app is running, 'NOT' in BACKGROUND the notification is disappearing and it directly go to the activity without clicking it, and how to stock notification?, because when i send more than one notification it only show the last message i sent, thanks for your help.

Comment: From what your telling me that sounds like standard behavior for Notifications. The recommendation for notifications is to only use 1 and change its display value. I'd recommend you read this for design guidelines and behavior details. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html